# How to reuse a spfile for creating a new Oracle Instance

Tags: oracle

I have an 11g Oracle XE instance I would like to clone to another instance named WE. So I did:

```
show parameter spfile ;
```

for getting the spfile directory path and name, next I did :

```
create pfile='/tmp/initWE.ora' from 
spfile='/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/spfileXE.ora
```

And then I replaced all XE entries in this file by WE. 
After restarting sqlplus I've got an Oracle Error

```
  startup pfile='/tmp/initWE.ora'

  ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
  Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
  Additional information: 9925
```

Should I change the ORACLE_SID ?

Comment: Did you change other path elements like `.../xe/...` to `..../we/...`, and if so do those new paths exist? (Does XE even allow you to run two DBs?)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the following parameter in your spfile (and subsequently pfile)

```
audit_file_dest
```

Whatever location this parameter references must *already* exist before you can start your instance, because we need to write a audit file entry the moment you connect as SYSDBA to the database. So precreate that folder/directory and you should be good to go